# Reproduce weather research, download and extract file using RStudio and wgrib2

Tags: r, rstudio, grib

**tl;dr**

First of all, all necessary code to reproduce the problem is available below. I'm experiencing some challenges with the ***grib*** part, but also with the more basic things with download.file()

**Problem**

There's a nice article on using GFS weather data in R [here](http://joewheatley.net/ncep-global-forecast-system/). It would be a great starting point for further analysis, but I'm having several problems. The article contains all R code required to reproduce it, but here are the first few lines which also is the most important part to get things going:

```
#STEP 1 (doesn't work either way because of bad link)
loc=file.path("ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2009121700/gfs.t00z.sfluxgrbf03.grib2")
```

My first problem was that the link didn't work, but here's the url to a file of the same format from the same source, so this  should work:

```
#PART 1 with working link (at least in google chrome):
loc=file.path("ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2015081112/gfs.t12z.sfluxgrbf00.grib2")
download.file(loc,"temp.grb",mode="wb")

#PART 2
shell("wgrib2 -s temp03.grb | grep :LAND: | wgrib2 -i temp00.grb -netcdf LAND.nc",intern=T)

#PART3
library(ncdf)
landFrac <-open.ncdf("LAND.nc")
land <- get.var.ncdf(landFrac,"LAND_surface")
x <- get.var.ncdf(landFrac,"longitude")
y <- get.var.ncdf(landFrac,"latitude")

#PART4
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("snow1","snow2","snow3","seagreen","orange","firebrick"), space = "rgb")#colors

image.plot(x,y,t2m.mean,col=rgb.palette(200),axes=F,main=as.expression(paste("GFS 24hr Average 2M Temperature",day,"00 UTC",sep="")),axes=F,legend.lab="o C")

contour(x,y,land,add=TRUE,lwd=1,levels=0.99,drawlabels=FALSE,col="grey30")
```

**My system**

Windows 7, 64 bit
Rstudio 0.99.467

**Question 1 - download.file()**

I'm having problems with download.file(), even with a link (or ftp path) that works fine in Chrome. Here's a part of the error message:

> In download.file(url = loc, destfile = "temp.grb", mode = "wb") :
>   InternetOpenUrl failed:

Anyone know what causes this?

**Question: 2 - wgrib2**

I've downloaded a sample file manually to get things going, but get stuck again in Part 2. How would the following r command look like directly in a command window?

```
shell("wgrib2 -s temp03.grb | grep :LAND: | wgrib2 -i temp00.grb -netcdf LAND.nc",intern=T)
```

I've installed the necessary dlls available under the links below, and I've also got wgrib 2 up and running (apparently). Information on wgrib2 is provided in the article, and available [here](http://www.cpc.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/). Source for [Windows 7](http://www.ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib2/Windows_7/).

I hope some of you find this interesting!

Comment: As for Question / Part 2, I doubt your Windows 7 install has grep.  You should be getting an error message from the shell command indicating what program(s) is missing.  If not, try running the contents of that string in a regular command shell (i.e., `cmd`).

Comment: Part 1 is likely your windows box, I just tried on Ubuntu and it's fine with your link and code. Perhaps you need to set `method=`?

Comment: There have been improvements in Windoze file downloading in the most recent version of R. You should update , read the NEWS files, and see whether that solves any problems.